# Is it possible to override (click) bining infor custom component in Angular?

Tags: angular

I have custom component that needs to be clickable but only if not in disabled state (just like native button do). I would like not to use custom event name, but instead reuse well known `(click)`

What I need is to stop execution of `(click)` binding if some conditions are met. However, no matter what I do with the event, it is still propagated to tke `(click)` binding.

Is there a way to override/supress execution of `(click)`?

```
<my-component (click)="someAction()">like a button</my-component>

export class ProgressButtonComponent{
    constructor(private ref: ElementRef) {
    ref.nativeElement.addEventListener('click', e => {
      console.log('ctor handler');
    });
  }
   @HostListener('click', ['$event'])
  hostlistenerclick(e: MouseEvent) {
    console.log('HostListener event');
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }  
}
```

parent:

```
someAction(){
   console.log("Custom user action");
}
```

Output:

```
ctor handler
HostListener event
Template bind event //this one I want to supress
```

Answer (score 0):

When the component is disabled, add a custom class to it, for instance `my-disabled` and then suppress pointer events via css. The class would look like this:

**CSS**

```
.my-disabled {
    pointer-events: none;
    cursor: default !important;
}
```

The first line stops events from happening, the second one gives your cursor the default look so it does not look clickable.

Using `ng-class`, you can now add or remove `my-disabled` to your component with the `click` based on your disabled logic